# Convert lists of Coordinates to Polygons with GeoPandas

Tags: python, pandas, geopandas

I got [lists of coordinates in the csv file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wggrf.png)(please click the pic). How should I convert them to polygons in GeoDataFrame?

Below is the coordinates of one polygon and I have thousands rows of this.

```
[118.103198,24.527338],[118.103224,24.527373],[118.103236,24.527366],[118.103209,24.527331],[118.103198,24.527338]
```

I tried the following codes:

```
def bike_fence_format(s):
    s = s.replace('[', '').replace(']', '').split(',')
    return s

df['FENCE_LOC'] = df['FENCE_LOC'].apply(bike_fence_format)

df['LAT'] = df['FENCE_LOC'].apply(lambda x: x[1::2])
df['LON'] = df['FENCE_LOC'].apply(lambda x: x[::2])

df['geom'] = Polygon(zip(df['LON'].astype(str),df['LAT'].astype(str)))
```

But I failed in the last step, since df['LON'] returns 'series' not 'string' type. How should I get over this problem? It's better if there is an easier way to achieve my goal.

Comment: Can you post some sample CSV data as text rather than image

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. I have updated the question.

Comment: Did you try my answer below? I think it should work for you. If it does, I'd love an up vote and accepted answer. If not, let me know and  I will update as needed.

Comment: @MatthewBorish He is not able to vote until his reputation is high enough. I give you one.

Answer (score 1):

Recreated a sample df of what your .csv file would give (depending on how your read it in with .read_csv()).

```
import pandas as pd
import geopandas as gpd

df = pd.DataFrame({'FENCE_LOC': ['[32250,175889],[33913,180757],[29909,182124],[28246,177257],[32250,175889]', 
                  '[32250,175889],[33913,180757],[29909,182124],[28246,177257],[32250,175889]', 
                  '[32250,175889],[33913,180757],[29909,182124],[28246,177257],[32250,175889]']}, index=[0, 1, 2])
```

Modified your function slightly because we want numeric values, not strings

```
def bike_fence_format(s):
    s = s.replace('[', '').replace(']', '').split(',')
    s = [float(x) for x in s]

    return s

df['FENCE_LOC'] = df['FENCE_LOC'].apply(bike_fence_format)


df['LAT'] = df['FENCE_LOC'].apply(lambda x: x[1::2])
df['LON'] = df['FENCE_LOC'].apply(lambda x: x[::2])
```

We can use some list comprehensions to build a list of Shapely polygons.

```
geom_list = [(x, y) for x, y  in zip(df['LON'],df['LAT'])]

geom_list_2 = [Polygon(tuple(zip(x, y))) for x, y in geom_list]
```

Finally, we can create a gdf using our list of Shapely polygons.

```
polygon_gdf =  gpd.GeoDataFrame(geometry=geom_list_2)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

To make available a small representative dataset similar to what the OP posts as an image, I create this rows of data (sorry for too many decimal digits):

```
[[-2247824.100899419,-4996167.43201861],[-2247824.100899419,-4996067.43201861],[-2247724.100899419,-4996067.43201861],[-2247724.100899419,-4996167.43201861],[-2247824.100899419,-4996167.43201861]]
[[-2247724.100899419,-4996167.43201861],[-2247724.100899419,-4996067.43201861],[-2247624.100899419,-4996067.43201861],[-2247624.100899419,-4996167.43201861],[-2247724.100899419,-4996167.43201861]]
[[-2247624.100899419,-4996167.43201861],[-2247624.100899419,-4996067.43201861],[-2247524.100899419,-4996067.43201861],[-2247524.100899419,-4996167.43201861],[-2247624.100899419,-4996167.43201861]]
[[-2247824.100899419,-4996067.43201861],[-2247824.100899419,-4995967.43201861],[-2247724.100899419,-4995967.43201861],[-2247724.100899419,-4996067.43201861],[-2247824.100899419,-4996067.43201861]]
[[-2247724.100899419,-4996067.43201861],[-2247724.100899419,-4995967.43201861],[-2247624.100899419,-4995967.43201861],[-2247624.100899419,-4996067.43201861],[-2247724.100899419,-4996067.43201861]]
[[-2247624.100899419,-4996067.43201861],[-2247624.100899419,-4995967.43201861],[-2247524.100899419,-4995967.43201861],[-2247524.100899419,-4996067.43201861],[-2247624.100899419,-4996067.43201861]]
[[-2247824.100899419,-4995967.43201861],[-2247824.100899419,-4995867.43201861],[-2247724.100899419,-4995867.43201861],[-2247724.100899419,-4995967.43201861],[-2247824.100899419,-4995967.43201861]]
[[-2247724.100899419,-4995967.43201861],[-2247724.100899419,-4995867.43201861],[-2247624.100899419,-4995867.43201861],[-2247624.100899419,-4995967.43201861],[-2247724.100899419,-4995967.43201861]]
[[-2247624.100899419,-4995967.43201861],[-2247624.100899419,-4995867.43201861],[-2247524.100899419,-4995867.43201861],[-2247524.100899419,-4995967.43201861],[-2247624.100899419,-4995967.43201861]]
```

This data is saved as `polygon_data.csv` file.

For the code, modules are loaded first as

```
import geopandas as gpd
import pandas as pd
from shapely.geometry import Polygon
```

Then, the data is read to create a dataframe by `pandas.read_csv()`. To get each row of data into a single column of the dataframe, `delimiter="x"` is used. Since there is no `x` within any row of data, the whole row of data as a long string is the result.

```
df3 = pd.read_csv('polygon_data.csv', header=None, index_col=None, delimiter="x")
```

To view the content of `df3`, you can run

```
df3.head()
```

and get single column (with header: 0) dataframe:

```
                                                   0
0  [[-2247824.100899419,-4996167.43201861],[-2247...
1  [[-2247724.100899419,-4996167.43201861],[-2247...
2  [[-2247624.100899419,-4996167.43201861],[-2247...
3  [[-2247824.100899419,-4996067.43201861],[-2247...
4  [[-2247724.100899419,-4996067.43201861],[-2247...
```

Next, `df3` is used to create a geoDataFrame. Data in each row of `df3` is used to create a Polygon object to act as the `geometry` of the geoDataFrame `polygon_df3`.

```
geometry = [Polygon(eval(xy_string)) for xy_string in df3[0]]
polygon_df3 = gpd.GeoDataFrame(df3, \
                   #crs={'init': 'epsg:4326'}, #uncomment this if (x,y) is long/lat
                   geometry=geometry)
```

Finally, the geoDataFrame can be plotted with a simple command:

```
# this plot the geoDataFrame
polygon_df3.plot(edgecolor='black')
```

In this particular case with my proposed data, the output plot is:

[image: 3x3sq]